# How to show post attachment image

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, attachments, images

i am going to create a slidershow by post attachment in single.php. i  use this code but the result is null.

```
<?php
        if ( have_posts() )
        while ( have_posts() ):
        the_post();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'   => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID
            );

        $attachments = get_posts( $args );

        if ( $attachments )
        {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment )
            {

            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, false );

            }
        }

        endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: This should show all attachments with the specified `post_parent`.  Are you sure the outer Loop executes and are you sure there are images attached to the posts in that Loop?

Comment: the image that i have attached before was from the media library

Comment: now i upload the another image and insert it to the post. it goes well

Comment: is there a method that i can show that image

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment.

Comment: the reason that the image didn't show was because i insert the image from the library, when i upload a new image to the library the uploaded images shows up as an attachment image.

Comment: now i want to show the image that i inserted from the library

Comment: Images that ___are not___ attached to post?